# Method that takes in integers or strings. C++

Tags: c++, methods, integer

So right now I'm trying to make a graphic C header file that could create shapes like triangle's, boxes, and circles in C++. Its supposed to help kids in my class, but I also want to be able for them to type stuff in the shapes. But I was wondering if there was a place holder for a integer in case you don't to cout<< a int.

For instance

the method (called up):

```
 //goes to coordinates 5,6 (creates side of 5 with a char called 'X')
 triangle(5,6,5,'X',"",5);
```

Will make a triangle with 2 sides of 5 units of X and have a regular base. But what if the user just wanted to print out the string w/o the integer. Then they would type

```
triangle(5,6,5,'X',"I love code", );
```

But an error would pop up and say that it needs one more parameter.

I've done some searching on boolean methods, like in java when you can type

```
public static void randommethod bool(/*params*\){

  /*Enter code if its either true or false*/

}
```

But I've come up empty with any trying to find a method like that in C++.

Comment: define 2 methods, one with the last param, one without. Overloading will work out which one you need

Comment: Maybe you should look into [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) and [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch waaay to complicated. Simple function overloads do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the title you probably want to be able to pass either int or string which will be printed as message. You can template your triangle function to accept anything:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void triangle(int x, int y, int z, char c, T anything)
{
    std::cout << anything << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    triangle(5, 6, 5, 'X', "I love code");
    triangle(5, 6, 5, 'X', 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Will print:

```
I love code
5
```

Comment: waaay too complex, simple function overloads work for him

Comment: @pm100 Difficult to tell what exactly he is looking for

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can implement function overloading to achieve your desired behavior. Take a look at [C++ Overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) to fully understand.  Here is a brief example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Shapes
{
    public:

        void triangle(int x,
                      int y,
                      int z,
                      char unit,
                      std::string & text,
                      int optional)
        {
            std::cout << "triangle with optional parameters" << std::endl;
        }

        void triangle(int x,
                      int y,
                      int z,
                      char unit,
                      std::string & text)
        {
            std::cout << "triangle with minimal parameters" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: Also, to not duplicate code, the overload with less parameters merely calls the overload with the greater number of parameters, with the optional argument(s) filled in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what each parameter corresponds to in your function, but if you want the last parameter to be optional, then you need to explicitly make it an optional parameter. When you create the function definition/prototype, you just assign the optional parameter the default value. If no value is provided, the default value is used.

For example, if I have a function to draw a triangle, I could write:

```
public void triangle(int base, int side1, int side2=1)
{
    ....
}
```

The side2 variable is optional. If no value is provided, 1 becomes the value. You could give the optional variable some kind of nonsense value that the function will detect and perform actions accordingly. Just make sure that the optional parameter is last in the list of parameters, otherwise it will give errors.

Hope this helps.